# Couting rows in MapReduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have created the following Map Reduce and came across something curious. I'm counting in 2 different ways the number of documents per date and coming up with different values. Here are my functions:

```
map : function Map() {
    emit(
        this.cDate,//Holds a date value
        {
        count: 1, 
        }
    );
}

reduce : function Reduce(key, values) {
    var reduced = {count:0,count1:0};
    values.forEach(function(val) {
        reduced.count += val.count; 
        reduced.count1++;
    });

return reduced;
}

finalize : function Finalize(key, reduced) {
    return reduced;
}

query : { "cDate" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z") } }

out : { inline : 1 }
```

So Basically what is strange is that at the end "count" and "count1" are returning different values. "count" has the correct value, that is, the number of documents for that date while "count1" has a much lower value. Can anyone explain (I'm new to MongoDB so use simple terms :-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems (which are really the same problem):

- Your emit format *must* be the same as your result returned in the emit function.
- Your reduce must be prepared to be called more than once for the same key (i.e. if you reduce five values for a key and then reduce three values for a key, the reduce function may be called again to reduce the result of two previous reduce operations.

Your example just demonstrates what happens if you assume that you will always be reducing the result "1" rather than the actual previously emitted *or* reduced result.

Reference:  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-ReduceFunction

Comment: Hi 1. Even if I add Count1 to the emit, I get the same result 2. wouldn't "count1" be the same or larger than "count" if reduce was called multiple times?

Comment: no, you are incrementing count1 by 1 instead of by passed in count - which you are assuming will always be 1, and that's not the case.

Comment: OK, So you are saying that even though I defined "count: 1" in emit, I won't always get 1 in the reduce because it may be a reduce on a reduce. yes?

Comment: Thanks. I have a related question But I will open a new Question tomorrow for it.

Comment: Asya, Perhaps you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580755/counting-documents-in-mapreduce-depending-on-condition-mongodb which is a followup to this quesiton