# Counting documents in MapReduce depending on condition - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to use a Map Reduce to count number documents according to one of the field values per date. First, here are the results from a couple of regular find() functions:

```
db.errors.find({ "cDate" : ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z") }).count();
```

returns 579 (ie. there are 579 documents for this date)

```
db.errors.find( { $and: [ { "cDate" : ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z") }, {"Type":"General"} ] } ).count()
```

returns 443 (ie. there are 443 documents for this date where Type="General")

Following is my MapReduce:

```
db.runCommand({ mapreduce: "errors", 
 map : function Map() {
    emit(
        this.cDate,//Holds a date value
        {
        count: 1,
        countGeneral: 1,
        Type: this.Type 
        }
    );
},

reduce : function Reduce(key, values) {
    var reduced = {count:0,countGeneral:0,Type:''};

    values.forEach(function(val) {
        reduced.count += val.count; 
        if (val.Type === 'General')
            reduced.countGeneral += val.countGeneral;
    });

return reduced; 
},

finalize : function Finalize(key, reduced) {
    return reduced;
},

query : { "cDate" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z") } },

out : { inline : 1 }
});
```

For the date 20-11-20 the map reduce returns:

```
count: 579

countGeneral: 60 (should be 443 according to the above find query)
```

Now, I understand that the Reduce is unpredictable in the way it loops so how should I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Two things I immediately see are: You don't need the `$and` in that query, MongoDBs default operator between array elements is `$and` and also in your query to get count you are getting all that equal `ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z")` but in your MR you are doing a `$gt` as such the two queries counts shouldn't match up. The total count of 579 does though, are you sure your MR is not working correctly?

Comment: The `$gte` is Okay since I'm grouping by cDate, the 60 was specifically what was returned for `ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z")`. there were other numbers for other dates but those are not important since I want to compare to the find query which was done for this date

Comment: Oh I saw it as `$gt` not `$gte`, hmm ok, this should count ok, when are you emitting the countGeneral to get the 60 you are?

Comment: Yes. It returns 60 and I know for a fact that there are more than 60 documents where the field "Type" is "General"

Comment: I wanna see something, if you were to change the query of the MR to match your first query does the `count` become 443?

Comment: I made the query part `query : { "cDate" : ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z") }` and the result was one document where count=579 and countGeneral=60. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Add on the `{"Type":"General"}` part as well, sorry I meant your second query, I need to wake up more.

Comment: OK. i used `query : { "$and" : [{ "cDate" : ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z") }, { "Type" : "General" }] }` ( I know, I don't need the `$and` but I want to be accurate) The results I got where:  count=443 and countGeneral=43. So, countGeneral is still returning a weird number

Comment: Aha we got `count` to return the right number (443) which means that it isn't the reduce causing the problem. There is something wrong about: `if (val.Type === 'General')` which is causing it to not work, hmm, if you change it to a loose comparison: `if (val.Type == 'General')` does it work?

Comment: changing `===` to `==` returned same number: 43

Comment: Your logic in emit is wrong.  You are emiting CountGeneral as 1 without testing whether type is General or not.

Comment: btw, @adinas - do not use $and operator when you don't need it - just do a normal comma separated JSON document.  There is nothing more "accurate" about using $and syntax, it just makes it harder to read.   As far as your problem - you need to fix your map and your reduce to output correct AND CONSISTENT format and then you will get the right values at the end.  You also have absolutely no need for `finalize` function so you should remove it entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I won't use the $and.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map function is wrong.
You could do something like this:

```
function Map() {
    var cG=0;
    if (this.Type == 'General') { cG=1; }
    emit(
        this.cDate,//Holds a date value
        {
        count: 1,
        countGeneral: cG
        }
    );
}
```

This emits countGeneral 1 if Type is 'General' and 0 otherwise.

Then you can remove the type check from your emit function entirely, since you're destroying    it anyway in your reduce function.  Currently your reduce clobbers Type information passed from emit during the reduce phase.

Comment: That may work, though if you read all the comments you'll realise it is confusing. When I made him change the query related to the MR the condition still did not return the right figures. It is a little confusing cos even with the dynamics of a MR it should have worked.

Comment: I think it's only confusing if you don't realize that reduce function may be called zero, once or many times.  I see problems in what was already tried that would directly lead to incorrect results.

Comment: But since `{ $and: [ { "cDate" : ISODate("2012-11-20T00:00:00Z") }, {"Type":"General"} ] }` returns all docs into the MR with a 1 value for the type condition wouldn't it just act the same as `reduced.count += val.count;` but always equal true on the condition and then add 1?

Comment: His reduce function is completely wrong.  Changing the "query" means the wrong map function will not matter, but the wrong reduce still causes a problem.

Comment: Well, indeed this worked and I added the other types and now the numbers returned all fit. unfortunately, it seems that doing anything in Reduce is almost pointless since you can't rely on it running per every document.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is exactly what "finalize" is for.  If there is work you need to do after all the reducing in complete (for example, calculate average after getting all the sums and counts) then you would do it in the finalize function.  But you have to do all the appropriate work in map function and not rely on reduce exclusively - reduce just aggregates multiple map outputs.

Comment: okay thanks. Hopefully I understand enough to get things now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you lose the rest of your values just because you don't return 'General' in your reduce part.

Reduce runs more than once for all the values emitted in the `map` part and returned from the `reduce` function.

For example, when the first iteration of reduce have run, you've got output object containing something like:

```
{count: 15, countGeneral: 3, Type: ''}
```

And other iterations of reduce collect this object and others like this one and don't see `Type:'General'` there and don't increase the `countGeneral` anymore.

Comment: Okay. So how do I fix this?

Comment: Try changing block `if (val.Type === 'General')
            reduced.countGeneral += val.countGeneral;` to `if (val.Type === 'General') {
            reduced.countGeneral += val.countGeneral; reduced.Type = 'General'; }` _Sorry for the markup - I can't use 'Enter' in comments_

Comment: It worked! So I tried `if (val.Type === 'General') { reduced.countGeneral += val.countGeneral;}
  reduced.Type = val.Type;` and again it gave the wrong number. wouldn't doing `reduced.Type = val.Type;` make sure it passed the 'General' on too?

Comment: You can't just use `reduced.Type = val.Type;` since your code is running through a collection of objects, and some of them have 'General' in their `type` while others don't. So, if the last element in your collection doesn't have the proper `type` value, you'll return the object (`reduced`) without 'General' in its `type`.

Comment: see my answer - I think you should fix your emit to do the right thing and then just simplify your reduce to increment two numbers, done.

Comment: Thanks. but indeed I 'General' was only one of many types which I wanted to add so reduced.Type = 'General'; just messed things up ultimately. Asya's solutions seems to work since I can add all the different types I need